# Is CSS content supposed to be shown if it includes an undeclared CSS variable?

Tags: css, css-variables, css-content

The following CSS code will generate different results depending on whether or not variable `--test2` is defined:

```css
html::before {
    content: "test1:" var(--test1) " test2:" var(--test2);
}
```

If `--test1` and `--test2` are defined, the test content will be displayed within the viewport.  If `--test1` is defined but `--test2` is ***not*** defined, ***none*** of the test content is displayed.

Is this the correct behavior, and if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#invalid-variables):

> A declaration can be invalid at computed-value time if it contains a `var()` that references a custom property **with its initial value**, as explained above, or if it uses a valid custom property, but the property value, after substituting its var() functions, is invalid. **When this happens, the computed value of the property is either the property’s inherited value or its initial** value depending on whether the property is inherited or not, respectively, as if the property’s value had been specified as the unset keyword.

In your case, you didn't define the variable so it has `initial` as value which will make `content` fallback to its initial value too (which is `none`) so nothing will show.

---

From the same Specification:

> When a custom property has its initial value, var() functions cannot use it for substitution. Attempting to do so makes the declaration **invalid at computed-value time, unless a valid fallback is specified**.

So better consider a fallback:

```css
html::before {
    content: "test1:" var(--test1,"") " test2:" var(--test2,"");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer, and the additional example code.  I'm trying to wrap my head around why the spec writers would want `content` to become *invalid* when any part of it contains a variable defined as CSS's `initial`.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket don't simply consider `content` because this apply to all the properties and it's logical. If a part inside a property cannot be resolved then the result is undefined so we fallback to initial OR inherited (not invalid, there is a difference). Ex: `padding:5px var(--p) 0` <-- if you don't define `p`, will it be 0 or what? the browser will simply ignore the whole value and use `padding:initial`

Comment: That's a great (and very helpful) way to think of it. Thanks. I do wonder, however, if CSS `content` should be treated a little differently because it actually adds content.  That said, since variables support fallback values, the workaround is not challenging or difficult to implement.

Comment: @RockPaperLz: I think that would introduce significant complexity for little gain. I agree with your conclusion.